# Examine a function regarding differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to prove that $f: \mathbb R^3 \setminus\{0\}  \to R : f(x) = \frac{e^{-\alpha \lVert x \rVert_2 }}{\lVert x \rVert_2 }$ is differentiable .

So, what I have to prove is that
$ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{1}{\lVert x-a\rVert_n}(f(x)-f(a)-L(x-a)) = 0$ , where $L$ is represented by the Jacobi-Matrix.

If I evaluate that, I get

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{\lVert x-a\rVert_n} \left[ 2 \frac{e^{-\alpha \lVert x \rVert_2 }}{\lVert x \rVert_2 } - \frac{e^{-\alpha \lVert a \rVert_2 }}{\lVert a\rVert_2 } - \frac{<x,a>}{\lVert x \rVert_2^3} e^{-\alpha \lVert x \rVert _2} -\alpha e^{-\alpha \lVert x \lVert_2 } + \alpha \frac{<x,a>}{\lVert x\rVert^2_2 } e^{-\alpha \lVert x \rVert}) \right] $$

As one can see, if $x \to a$ the brackets approaches $0$, but so does the factor $\frac{1}{\lVert x-a\rVert_n}$ , so I basically have $\frac{0}{0} $.

Is there a smoother way to prove differentiability ?

Comment: You probably know that sums, products, quotients (where the denominator doesn't vanish) and compositions of differentiable functions are differentiable. Breaking things up using these, there's almost nothing left to do.

Comment: What do you mean with "there's almost nothing left to do" ?

Comment: Let $g(t) = \dfrac{e^{-at}}{t}$, and $h(x) = \lVert x\rVert_2$. You can most likely use the differentiability of $g$ (on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$) without proof. Now for $h$ ...

Comment: Well, I get that $h(x)$ is not differentiable ... Applying the definition gives me:
$\lim_{\lVert v \rVert \to 0 } \frac{1}{\lVert v \rVert} (\lVert v \rVert_2 + \frac{\vec a \vec v }{\lVert a \rVert^3_2})$ , which does not converge to $0$ ...

Comment: I don't see how you could get that. Write $h$ as the composition of $s(t) = \sqrt{t}$ and $q(x) = \lVert x\rVert_2^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2$ to get something a little simpler to handle.